Automatically extend values in accordance with the specified conditions
The simple data is:
df <- structure(list(value1 = c(-2.42288252774916), value2 = c(-1.99988470731567), value3 = c(-1.57678745345913)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                             ), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

I am trying to build a code that could produce the results as this:
NEW.df <- structure(list(value1 = c(-2.42288252774916), value2 = c(-1.99988470731567), value3 = c(-1.57678745345913), NEWvalue1 = c(-2.98), NEWvalue2 = c(-1.99988470731567), NEWvalue3 = c(-1.02)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

"NEWvalue1" was created by extending "-2.42288252774916" toward '-2.98', 'NEWvalue2' didn't change and 'NEWvalue3' was created by extending '-1.57678745345913' toward '-1.02'.

To clarify further:
"NEWvalue1" is like to (almost) nearest smallest integer (-3 <-2.42288252774916). For 'NEWvalue3' it is like to (almost) nearest largest integer (-1.57678745345913 <-1.02). If '-2.98' and '-1.02' sound too complicated, it can be "-3" and "-1" instead.

"NEWvalue1" extends the "value1"  from "-2.42288252774916" to '-2.98','NEWvalue3' extends "value3"  '-1.57678745345913' to '-1.02'.

for "NEWvalue1" it is like to (almost) nearest smallest integer (-3<-2.42288252774916). For 'NEWvalue3'  it is like to (almost) nearest largest integer (-1.57678745345913 <-1.02). If '-2.98'  and '-1.02' sound too complicated, it can be "-3" and "-1" instead

Maybe we need round, try: c(round(df$value1) - 1, df$value2, round(df$value3) + 1)

Using floor and ceiling functions:
cbind(df, 
      NEWvalue1 = floor(df$value1) + 0.02,
      NEWvalue2 = df$value2,
      NEWvalue3 = ceiling(df$value3) - 0.02)

#      value1    value2    value3 NEWvalue1 NEWvalue2 NEWvalue3
# 1 -2.422883 -1.999885 -1.576787     -2.98 -1.999885     -1.02


This is what I have been looking for. I guessed the correct code had to do something with floor and ceiling, or with dyplar, yet could not compile a right solution. Thank you so much!
